# ¿ Como obtener la licencia OEM de windows directamente de la BIOS del PC mediante JAVA?

Tags: java, windows, registro-windows

Me encuentro desarrollando un programa de inventario de computadores para la empresa en la que trabajo el cual es capaz de identificar hardware y demas caracteristicas de la máquina, sin embargo en el inventario debe ir:

- distribucion de windows
- id del producto
- licencia instalada y
- licencia de la BIOS

Esta última me ha sido imposible obtenerla ya que no se como hallar la licencia OEM de la BIOS del PC, el programa lo he desarrollado en JAVA.

He intentado utilizar este código pero no me funciona, se queda en una espeia de LOOP pero no se por que,

```
String comando = "powershell.exe (Get-WmiObject -query 'SELECT OEMStringArray FROM Win32_ComputerSystem').OA3xOriginalProductKey ";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
String line;
System.out.println("Standard Output:");
BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("hola");
    System.out.println(line);
}
stdout.close();
System.out.println("Standard Error:");
BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getErrorStream()));
while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
stderr.close();
System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar WMIC? Podrías obtener los datos desde esa herramienta y pasar el resultado a tu aplicación Java.

Comment: String comando = "(Get-WmiObject -query 'SELECT OEMStringArray FROM Win32_ComputerSystem').OA3xOriginalProductKey ";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);

Comment: @FernandoCarraro intente correr las lineas de codigo en java pero se revienta el programa y me dice que no  puede encotrar el archivo especificado sin embargo si no estoy mal es un comando para powershell lo corro directamente de la consola y la consulta no arroja ningun resultado, se me ovido agregar que necesito que el metodo funcione tanto para windows 7,8  y 10, muchas gracias.

Comment: @FernandoCarraro de  echo no se que comando de wmic lo puede hacer, gracias.

Comment: Respuesta modificada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando funciona perfectamente.
[image: ejecución de comando en PowerShell]

En Java podrías usar algo como esto:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.system.err;
//...
//...
    try{
                String result = null;
    //String comando = "(Get-WmiObject -query 'SELECT OEMStringArray FROM Win32_ComputerSystem').OA3xOriginalProductKey ";

//Obtener información del BIOS
//String comando = "WMIC /Output:STDOUT BIOS get /all /format:LIST";

    String comando = "wmic baseboard get serialnumber";

                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
                    result += line;
                }
                if(result.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
                    out.println("El resultado esta vacio");
                } else{
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,result);
                }
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException ex){
                err.println("Ha ocurrido una excepcion");
                err.println("Estas en una plataforma ajena a Windows?");
                //ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Te dejo este post sobre el uso de WMIC https://norfipc.com/comandos/informacion-pc-uso-wmic.html

Existen varias combinaciones para usar WMIC y obtener lo que requieres

Comment: Gracias pero he intentado utilizar el codigo con algunas modificaciones para que pueda funcionar pero aun no lo logro agradezco si lo miras,actualice la pregunta.

Comment: Copie y pegue el codigo y al ejecutar el comando de la licencia me aparece la siguente excepcion: `Ha ocurrido una excepcion
Estas en una plataforma ajena a Windows?
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "(Get-WmiObject": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Comment: Necesitas habilitar el PowerShell. Abre una terminal en Windows y escribe: set-executionpolicy remotesigned y da Enter.  
¿Has probado usar WMIC? Yo ejecuté el código en una PC con Windows 10 y funciona bien.